# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ssm.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services

When trying to do any AWS command, like aws ssm start-session --target database, I got the error like this:

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ssm.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com/"

```
region = us-east-1b
output = json
```

not sure how to get the SSM work based on the error message.
Where is this endpoint URL coming from?

Comment: The command is executed where exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You are pointing your region to an Availability Zone `us-east-1b` rather than an AWS region `us-east-1`.

Changing your region to `us-east-1` will resolve the problem.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-region
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html